# how to update firebase data

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to update status = 0 in firebase database where status = 1.

What I have tried is:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Kreait\Firebase\Configuration;
use Kreait\Firebase\Firebase;
$firebase = new Firebase('LINK', $configuration);
$users = $firebase->get('/users');
for ($i=0; $i < count($users) ; $i++) {
    $data = array('status' => '0');
    $nodeUpdateContent = $firebase->update(['status' => '1'],$users[$i].'/presence/status');
    print_r($nodeUpdateContent);
}
?>
```

But when I see in the firebase database, it is not updating anything. Why so?

I am following this link: [Firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/tree/c0adb0ced970b2a8a2968a7bf6f803786a2f7ca2)

Update data using this link: [Update-data](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/master/doc/firebase.md)

I am getting in `$users`:

```
<?php
[1] => Array
(
    [presence] => Array
    (
        [loginTimestamp] => 1460117596561
        [status] => 1
    )

)

[2] => Array
(
    [presence] => Array
    (
        [loginTimestamp] => 1460117596561
        [status] => 1
    )
)

[3] => Array
(
    [presence] => Array
    (
        [loginTimestamp] => 1460117596561
        [status] => 1
    )
)

?>
```

I am getting response for this: 
**$nodeUpdateContent = $firebase->update(['status' => '1'],$users[$i].'/presence/status');**

```
Array
(
    [status] => 1
)
Array
(
    [status] => 1
)
Array
(
    [status] => 1
)
Array
(
    [status] => 1
)
Array
(
    [status] => 1
)
```

`It is just printing the status which value is 1, but not updating it.`

**EDIT:**

```
getting error here: Array to string conversion --> $nodeUpdateContent = $firebase->update(['status' => '1'],$users[$i].'/presence/status');
```

Comment: see if http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php helps any.

Comment: @Fred-ii- why error reporting? I am asking for Firebase update

Comment: heck... I don't know. path issues?! config issues, the list goes on. check on db side too

Comment: I don't know. It is echoing the status as  it is. not updataing the data @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred-ii- I checked the error log and it giving error on this link `$nodeUpdateContent = $firebase->update(['status' => '1'],'/users/'.$users[$i].'/presence');` error is: **PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion*

Comment: What is content of $users ? If echo $users ? If print_r($users) ?

Comment: @J.Grunder Please see the update question

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the below git that I have created

> https://github.com/eldhosemjoy/firebase

According to the above git,

```
$updated_json = array(
                    "loginTimestamp" => 1460117596561,
                    "status" => 2,
                 );
```

This is to update at the first position

```
$fboject->path = "/users/1";
$fboject->updateData($updated_json);
```